# Setting a selected option from controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs to make a search page where the user can use filters to search for the items they want. If the user leaves this page and then comes back, I want the select tag to display what they had before. For example if the user filters out the items with a minimum price of $0 and then leaves the page but comes back to it, I want the select tag to display $0. This is my html...

```
            <p><b> Minimum Price: </b>
                <select class="form-control" style="width:30%" data-ng-model="minPrice" ng-options="number for number in price track by number">
                </select>
            </p>
```

and this is my controller ...

```
    $scope.search = function() {

        if( $scope.minPrice == "None") {
            $scope.minPrice = "";
        } 

        // get the search query
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/RealEstate/houseListing/filter?" + "minPrice=" + $scope.minPrice + "&maxPrice=" + $scope.maxPrice + "&bedsTotal=" + $scope.beds + "&bathsTotal=" + $scope.baths)
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.result = response;
            alert($scope.result);

            sessionStorage.minPrice = $scope.minPrice;
            sessionStorage.result = true;
        })
    }

    if(sessionStorage.result != null) {

        // restore the last search
        $scope.minPrice = sessionStorage.minPrice;
        $scope.search();

    } else {
```

I've shortened the code to make it easier to read but to be precise, I want the select tag to show the option that the user chose before. I've saved the value into a sessionStorage and then tried to restore it when the page is loaded if it exists but the select tag doesnt show anything.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the code posted, you'll have to post more code.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible. Here's a working plunker based on your code, where I even write the value for minPrice to sessionstorage and then read it back out for the selected value of the select model:

http://plnkr.co/edit/n2miUv?p=preview

js

```
$scope.price = [10, 11, 13, 100, 33, 57];

// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('minPrice', 13);
// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('minPrice');

$scope.minPrice = data;
```

html

```
<p>
  <b> Minimum Price: </b>
  <select class="form-control" style="width:30%" 
    ng-model="minPrice"
    ng-options="number for number in price track by number"></select>
</p>
```

I suspect you may have an issue with your the value you're trying to bind if it isn't working.